# AWS CDK: Get HttpRoute of given api defined in another stack

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I have two stacks, stack A defines a HTTP Api with a route "/convert". Now I would like to import this route in stack B.

I managed to import the http api from stack A, but there seems to be now way to access routes from this API.

```
const httpApiId = cdk.Fn.importValue("CurrencyApiId");
    const api = HttpApi.fromHttpApiAttributes(this, "api", { httpApiId });

// const convertRoute: HttpRoute = ????
```

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to retrieve an API routes in CDK (the `apigateway` module is still quite new and quickly evolved over the last few months). In your stack A, you may have to store the routes in a dictionary, for it to be reused in stack B.

Answer (score 0):

CDK constructs (the actual classes you use to define a resource) are defined as L1, L2, or L3 constructs. L1 are the very base methods. usually prefixed with `cfn` they are bare bones just basic creation of a cloudformation template.

L2 and L3 constructs meanwhile make use of OOP and abstraction from the L1 underneath them to create various hooks that you use for interacting. When you give a lambda function object to an apigateway integration for instance, this is using L3 constructs to "hook" the lambda into the api gateway, and all the necessary cloud formation pieces are done for you on the back end.

Unfortunately, many of these things are only possible if the stack controls all parts - When you import (using the various `from` prefixed methods) CDK is just using an SDK (or aws cli) command to go out and retrieve the information from your account. Some things are not able to be processed using these `from` methods because they either could change between Synth of the template and deployment, or they are ephemeral, or many other reasons. As such, many times the 'construct' object created by a `from` method is missing many things.

You would be better served by passing this value into the second stack. Preferably with both as Nested Stacks amid a common application stack above them

(python psuedo code below, because thats what I'm more familiar with, but it applies to all languages of CDK)

```
class CommonMainStack(cdk.Stack):
    api_stack = ApiStack()
    stack_that_uses_methods = OtherStack(api_stack.http_methods)

class ApiStack(cdk.NestedStack):
    api = HttpApi()
    self.http_methods = api.http_methods

class OtherStack(cdk.NestedStack):

    whatever_needed_for(imported_methods)
```

this will allow you to make use of all the L2/L3 construct hooks immediately

Comment: Thank you. I basically understand the way CDK works. Unfortunately, nesting the stacks is no solution in this case, as both units need to be independently deployable. The api route was only needed for granting an IAM permission, which can also be solved by explicitly declaring the route as a string.

Comment: If its for something like "I'll need to call this api in this stack in order to get specific information" then yeah - thats better stored as a Env Variable or a Parameter Store - If its always going to be in the same account, you can have stack A put that value in a Parameter Store and have stack B retrieve it on Synth. 

Alternately - you can just use `cfn.output` in Stack A to output any generated data you need - you can have the synth/deploy functiouns put these outputs into a json file and have Stack B look for that json file and import the values